# Function returning different values inside another function

Tags: c, function

My first function checks for the number of letters that a substring contains from its string.

```
int num_matches(char* word, char* letters) {
    char scrabble[128];
    strcpy(scrabble, letters);
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        if (strchr(letters, word[i]) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(letters); j++) {
            if (word[i] == letters[j]) {
                num++;
                scrabble[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return num;
}
```

It returns 4 for "QWOP", "QWOP". However, inside the following function it is returning the same incorrect value for every function call, even when buff and letters print as "QWOP", "QWOP" from my debugging attempt.

```
void read_words(int num_count[128], char* (*word_idx)[128], int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char* letters = argv[2];

    int idx = 0;
    char buff[128];
    int result = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, 128, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("buff:%s letters:%s\n", buff, letters);
        result = num_matches(buff, letters);
        printf("result: %d\n", result);
        num_count[idx] = result;
        char* word = malloc(strlen(buff) + 1);
        strcpy(word, buff);
        (*word_idx)[idx] = word;
        idx++;
        result = 0;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

```
buff:QWOP
 letters:QWOP
result: -1
```

My txt file:

```
ABC
DEFG
QWOP
QWOP
QUOKKA
QUOLL
QUASH
QUANDONG
```

Since fgets stops at a newline and there are no spaces in my text file, I don't think there should be any problems with reading buff.

Comment: Place some debugging outputs in the function itself to see what it's doing instead of guessing

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have placed many printf statements and have been inspecting it for an absurd time but still don't understand. The only reason I can think of is that there are spaces before the newline in the buffer. But I don't see how the text file can cause this.

Comment: When you use `printf("buff:%s letters:%s\n", buff, letters);` to print the 2 strings and the second one is on the next line, then the first one has a `'\n'` at the end, which will fail at the `strchr`, because it is not a letter.

Comment: Explain what is `char* (*word_idx)[128]`. I think that is not what you think it is

Comment: @0___________ I think it is a pointer to a char* array of length 128. I guess I did not have to pass a pointer to the array, because the char* array automatically decays into a pointer and so I can edit its memory contents without returning it?

Comment: @cwonder so you want pointer to array of 128 pointers?

Comment: @0___________ yes

Comment: @Cwonder do you know what `(*word_idx)[idx] = word;`does?

Comment: @0___________ I'm pretty confident now that it allocates the value of char* word (memory address on the heap of the first character) to the index idx in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets reads the data with `\n` character at the end.

Your function will fail in this case. It is very easy to test:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", num_matches("ABCD", "ABCD"));
    printf("%d\n", num_matches("ABCD\n", "ABCD"));
}
```

Result:

```
4
-1
```

You need to remove `\n` from the buff.

Another problem is the second function. The parameter `char* (*word_idx)[128]` is a pointer to an array of 128 pointers to char. I do not think that is something you want.